# How to remove wrinkles from a crumpled piece of paper?

Tags: stationery

Some paper crafts require folding and then cutting in shapes.
The problem is that the  unwanted folds remain visible. Assuming that the paper can be opened fully, what should be done to remove the fold marks on the paper?

Comment: you could maybe fold it many more times so it gives the paper nice naturalish texture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iron it with not very hot iron (not to burn the paper).
Another trick is to put it under some heavy books for several days.

Comment: Yes. The fold marks will still be visible, but you really can't fix that. Ironing is the way to go.

Comment: Adding slight amounts of water also helps when you iron, but always add pressure when drying. Iron by covering the paper to protect the paper.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a faster but not as effective way to smooth out paper, you can run the paper over the edge of a desk. (Pretend like the paper is a string and the edge of the desk is a pulley wheel) The rollers in printers also use the this principle.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an A4 size paper, it's very easy to remove the wrinkles. Keep the paper on a printer's tray. Open MS Word and make a printout (ensure the MS Word file is blank). That makes the wrinkled paper to go through the printer and all its wrinkles will go away.

Comment: Surely you would have to run a sheet of paper through a printer several hundred times for that to work.

Comment: If the paper is wrinkled a bit too much or if the printer is very sensitive this is the way to get the paper jam in the printer, often ruining the paper.

Answer (score 1):

The paper fibres are broken. The damage is one-way. There's no going back once the damage is done.

But while you can't remove folds or wrinkles from a sheet of paper, **you can leave wrinkles and folds behind.**

Make a pattern by folding, wrinkling, cutting, etc. Then, use that original as a pattern to trace onto flat, unwrinkled, and clean unfolded paper for the final finished product.